# sencha , phonegap android application going black for a long time

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch, cordova-2.0.0

I am developing a sencha + phonegap android application. I am very new to this and I developed an app be reading some tutorial. 
I am using ADT for developing.

My application showing a blank screen for a 5-6 seconds while loading even its a simple "Hello World" application.

My index.html looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>PhoneGap</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="sencha-touch-all.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="sencha-touch.css" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript"> 

Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
            fullscreen: true,
            html: 'Hello World'
        });
    }
});

</script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Remains all are working fine.

I had some more doubts also

1. The application won't load when I connect "cordova-2.2.0.js" in my index.html.

   Not need to load cordova-2.2.0.js in index.html file for sencha application ?

I has been stucked here

Comment: Are you running on device or in emulator? Emulator is horribly slow.

Comment: I am running in device .. just rightclick on the application > Run As Android app > select the connected device .. but getting black screen

Comment: I will recommend you checking the Android console, to know what is  going on in background, if there is any issue you can post here.

Comment: Where are you loading cordova file in relation to the other script files? Before or after sencha-touch-all? Also, why are you setting a charset on sencha-touch-all?